# Can a Foreign Key be part of a Composite Primary Key for another table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have two(of many) tables in a music database:

Concerts: ArtistID,ConcertID,ConcetName,VenueID
ConcertDetails: ConcertDate, ConcertID, Cost

The ConcertDetails tables as you see, uses ConcertID which is also in the Concerts table. I combine ConcertDate & ConcertID to make a Composite Primary Key for ConcertDetails. However since this relates to ConcertID from Concerts table it also needs to be a Foreign Key. Is this ok to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, of course. It's common for a subset of a primary key to be a foreign key. Any many-to-many table does this for instance.  In your case:

```
CREATE TABLE ConcertDetails (
  ConcertDate DATE NOT NULL,
  ConcertID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ConcertDate, ConcertID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ConcertID) REFERENCES Concerts(ConcertID)
);
```