# How to use part of foreign key which is composite primary key of another table as a primary key in hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have 2 tables.. Table A contains composite primary key. I am using this key as a foreign key in another table. but in this table i need to have a composite primary key  where one of the column i need to take it from the composite key of A table. I could not achieve this with mapsId as it is taking a whole CK. is there anyway to achieve it?

i just need hibernate way of doing like below:

[I need exactly like this in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576974/can-a-foreign-key-be-part-of-a-composite-primary-key-for-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could map the entities corresponding to the database tables in the SO question you linked to:

```
@Entity
public class Concert {
  @Id
  Integer id;

  String name;

  ...
}


@Embeddable
public class ConcertDetailsId {
  Date date;

  Integer concertId; // corresponds to PK type of Concert
}


@Entity
public class ConcertDetails {
  @EmbeddedId
  ConcertDetailsId id;

  @MapsId("concertId") // maps concertId attribute of embedded id
  @ManyToOne
  Concert concert;

  BigDecimal cost;

  ...
}
```

Is this how you tried to use `@MapsId`? If so, what was the problem?

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: In my case concert has a composite key where I need one column of it  not the whole ck.. I will use this column and other column in another table as ck

Comment: So, that is *not* "exactly" like the tables you linked to in your question. : ) If the `ConcertDetails` foreign key uses only a single field in `Concert`, that field must be unique in the `Concert` table. Is that correct? If so, you simply use that single field as the `Concert` primary key (for Hibernate).

Comment: my bad, i have linked a wrong one.. sorry on that. assume that the concert has composite key containing 2 field.. i want to use only 1 field of it as a primary key on another table.how is that possible?

Comment: As I mentioned in my earlier comment, if the `Concert` field is *unique* by itself (which it would have to be for your `ConcertDetails` foreign key to work), you might be able to get away with putting an `@Id` annotation on only that single field and leave the other half of the primary key as a `@Basic` mapping.